# MacOS Swifで作るComboboxのActionメソッドについて

Tags: swift, macos

MacOSでSwiftを用いた画面作成について教えて下さい。

storyboardでViewController上に2つのComboboxを置いて、それぞれのクリック時の動作を制御したいのですが、前にクリックしたコンボボックスのActionメソッドにも飛んでしまいます。

### ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cmb1: NSComboBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var cmb2: NSComboBox!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


    @IBAction func selCmb1(_ sender: NSComboBox) {
        print("pushCmb1")
    }


    @IBAction func selCmb2(_ sender: NSComboBox) {
        print("pushCmb2")
    }

}
```

コンボボックス１クリック、コンボボックス２をクリックした時に表示されたprint文が
下記になります。

①コンボボックス１選択し、プルダウンでアイテム表示
②アイテム選択
　pushCmb1
③コンボボックス２選択、プルダウンでアイテム表示
　pushCmb1
④アイテム選択
　pushCmb2

となり、③のコンボボックス２を選択した際に、コンボボックス１のActionメソッドが動いてしまいます。
そもそもプルダウンでアイテム表示した際のActionメソッドが不要で、アイテム選択時のみActionメソッドに飛んで欲しいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSCombobox`に対しては、Actionメソッドでなく、`NSComboBoxDelegate`（https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscomboboxdelegate）を使ってください。その中にある、`comboBoxSelectionDidChange(_:)`を使えば、「アイテム選択時のみ」「飛んで欲しい」メソッドとすることができます。

> ③のコンボボックス２を選択した際に、コンボボックス１のActionメソッドが動いてしまいます。

その判断は、じつは正しくありません。いくつかの検証をしてみればわかりますが、コンボボックスが、キーボードの入力対象から外れたタイミングで、Actionメソッドが送られることが確認できます。キーボードの入力対象が、コンボボックスから例えば`NSTextField`に移った時にも、そうなります。「コンボボックス２を選択した際」、「コンボボックス２」が、「コンボボックス１のActionメソッド」を送っているわけではありません。

Comment: nagonsoftware さん、ありがとうございます。comboBoxSelectionDidChangeを使用する事で無事出来ました！また、後半のメソッドが動く件も試してみたらおっしゃる通りでした。そうすると疑問がわくのですが、このActionメソッドの使い方というか、どういうときに役にたつのかです。入力対象が外れたときに動いてほしい動作があるってことなんでしょうか。

Comment: とりあえずは、やりたい動作は出来ました。nagonsoftware さん、本当にありがとうございました。